# How to avoid round off and scientific notation in double in scala?

Tags: scala

Given:

```
scala> val s =99999999999999947.89
s: Double = 9.9999999999999952E16
scala> f"$s%.2f"
res15: String = 99999999999999952.00
```

i want output should be = 99999999999999947.89

> how to avoid round off and scientific notation both.

Comment: So you want a value that can not be precise for physical reasons to be precise like for art of magic? - if you need that level of precision you need to use a **BigDecimal** with the appropriate **MathContext**. Also, remember that to use **Strings** or **Ints** for creating the firsts **BigDecimals** to ensure they are precise.

Comment: Hey, is there any other way to handle double and obtain the given value?

Comment: Probably not. There's only so much information you can hold in 64 bits. I think they can have about 16 sig figs, and this is more than that

Comment: @varsha You do not know [how floating-point numbers are represented in a computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) do you?

Comment: BTW, this is not a Scala's limitation - IEEE 754 mentioned by @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez is how numbers are natively supported by processors which is why virtually all popular programing languages have them working the same way. If you need greater precision you have to emulate this either in library (like BigDecimal on JVM) or by language (but it will use something like BigDecimal under the hood).

Answer (score 1):

The `Double` datatype doesn't support the precision you're after. The closest number 99999999999999952 is the number closest to 99999999999999947.89 that can be represented as a `Double`.

That's not just the case for very big numbers. Double values can soon start to drift. You can see this for example in that `(0.2 + 0.2 + 0.2) != 0.6`

Use a [`BigDecimal`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.2/scala/math/BigDecimal.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

In Scala, longs and floats with high precision are automatically converted into scientific notation.

However we often DONT want this behavior especially when passing data in say, json format between applications because the receiving application may not know how to correctly interpret a string that looks like this:

"1.68047475E+9"

as a floating point number.

The answer that I have found is that in Scala, when you try to convert a Numeric Type to a String, the default behavior is to preserve the precision by using scientific notation. If you find that you DON'T want your number to be represented like that, you need to convert it into a more precise datatype before converting it into a string.

For example

```
(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000).toDouble.toString
```

will return

`1680475334`

(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000).toFloat.toString

will return

`1.68047539E+9`

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to keep BigDecimal type instead of converting it to String, you can do

```
BigDecimal(rs.getBigDecimal("column_name").stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString())
```